# Is there any function for HDFS to get today's date?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to schedule -mkdir to make directory everyday with the date of the day.

Is there any way to get today's date for the command:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /home/<date>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the linux `date` command

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /home/`date +%Y%m%d`
```

Comment: It's not working. The above command created directory /home/date +%Y%m%d

Comment: Thanks! I am using ' instead of ` just now.